# How do I translate a query that uses ROW_NUMBER() into linq?

Tags: c#, linq

My table consists of three columns (sno,name,age). I am retrieving this table from the database with extra column (row number) and I used the following code:

```sql
select * from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SNo asc)as rowindex,SNo,Name,Age 
    from tblExample) 
    as example where rowindex between ((pageindex*10)+1) and ((pageindex+1)*10)
```

Note, pageindex is the variable that takes some integer value which is passed by the user.

My database is Sql Server 2008. I want to write the same query using Linq. How do I do that?

Comment: LINQ to SQL? LINQ to EF?

Comment: Without pulling the entire set and possibly using a variable or the overloaded `.Select` operator, I don't believe there is a LINQ command that will translate to this query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write query as beow

```
var index=1;
var pageIndex=1;
var pageSize = 10;
data.Select(x => new
{
    RowIndex = index++,
    Sno = x.Sno,
    Name = x.Name,
    Age = x.Age
}).OrderBy(x => x.Name)
.Skip(pageSize * (pageIndex - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: `An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator` How exactly does this work for you (without locally caching the list first)?

Comment: @Simon Belanger: His requirement is to do paging dynamically in grid view with help of linq. In this case the above scenario works perfectly. try your self its working perfectly for me

Answer (score 7):

Not a *direct* translation, but since your row number only appears to be used for paging, try:

```
db.tblExample
  .OrderBy(t => t.SNo)
  .Select((t,i) => new {rowindex = i+1, t.SNo, t.Name, t.Age })
  .Skip(pageIndex * 10)
  .Take(10);
```

**EDIT**

If `Select((t,i) => ...)` doesn't work you can try synthesizing the index number by adding it after hydrating the query:

```
db.tblExample
  .OrderBy(t => t.SNo)
  .Skip(pageIndex * 10)
  .Take(10)
  .AsEnumerable();
  .Select((t,i) => new {rowindex = (pageIndex*10)+i+1, t.SNo, t.Name, t.Age })
```

You should end up with *equivalent* SQL other than the fact that the `rowindex` field will not be returned from the SQL query, but will instead be added by the member selection expression.

Comment: Can't use the `.Select(Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>)` overload to build a query (`Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'.`), the results have to be locally stored first. So, if this is a DB context, you'd have to call `.ToList()` (or equiv) first.

Comment: I'd advise against calling `.ToList()` before the `.Select()` as it's written here; that'd load everything to memory which defeats the purpose of the paging. Instead, do the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` first, then `.ToList()` that, then `.Select()` the result into your output format.

Comment: @anaximander: it _has_ to be loaded in to memory to use the overload; that's what I was referring to with `Unsupported overload...`.

Comment: I'm aware of that - my point is that if you're going to load it to memory with `.ToList()` or similar, you should do if *after* you've cut it down to one page worth. I've seen plenty of SO questions asking why paging with `.Skip()` and `.Take()` wasn't making it any faster, where the answer was that asker was calling `.ToList()` *before* paging, thus rendering it somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Best-case scenario (if you *need* the metadata):

```
var rows = db.tblExample           // database context
           .OrderBy(x => x.SNo)  // set an orderby
           .AsEnumerable()       // force query execution (now we have local dataset)
           .Select(x => new
           {
               rowindex = i,
               SNo = x.Sno,
               Name = x.Name,
               Age = x.Age
           });                   // now you have your original query
```

The only downfall here is that the *entire dataset must be pulled* to get this metadata. However, if you use `.Skip` & `.Take` and LINQ will automatically translate that in to a rownumber for you (you just won't be able to use that metadata later). e.g.

```
var pageIndex = /* ??? */;
var rows = db.tblExample
           .OrderBy(x => x.SNo)
           .Skip(pageIndex * 10).Take(10);
```

which should give you something like:

```
SELECT [t1].[SNo] AS [SNo],
       [t1].[Name] AS [Name],
       [t1].[Age] AS [Age]
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[tblExample], [t0].[SNo]) AS [ROW_NUMBER],
         [t0].[SNo],
         [t0].[Name],
         [t0].Age]
  FROM   [tblExample] AS [t0]
) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

So now the `row_number` is used internally within SQL, but you're not able to get access to it within your code.

If you really want this kind of access, you may be better off manually sending the query to the server. One lib that works well with this sort of thing is [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), which would look something like:

```
class MyObject {
    public Int32 rowindex;
    public Int32 SNo;
    public String Name;
    publig Int32 Age;
}

/* build "connection" */

connection.Query<MyObject>("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() ... ) ...");
```

Comment: Actually, you *can* get the row number by using a little-known overload of `.Select()` which looks something like this: `.Select((x, i) => new {Index = i, Item = x})`, which results in an object where `obj.Index` is the row number.

Comment: @anaximander: that overload doesn't have a SQL translation though, so it's only valid while the data is _local_. that means if you have 10k records, you have to have all 10k in an enumerable before you can use the overload. (The error that occurs was listed as a comment to D Stanley's answer)

Comment: Indeed. However, if you're using `.Skip()` and `.Take()`, chances are you're using them for paging, and the whole point of paging is to break your result set into manageable chunks. If your pages are large enough that loading the collection to memory is a problem, then you're doing paging wrong.