# Using Row_Number of SQL Server in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with data like

```
Date         Users
------------------
01/03/2015    25
02/03/2015    28
04/03/2015    36
07/03/2015    45
08/03/2015    47
```

I had created a table valued function in Sql Server using Row_Number which gave me output like below which I used for further processing

```
Date         Users      UsersAdded
----------------------------------
01/03/2015    25        0
02/03/2015    28        3
04/03/2015    36        8
07/03/2015    45        9
08/03/2015    47        2
```

However, I need to do the same thing in Linq now but it does not has the Row_Number function. I had a look at [How do I translate a query that uses ROW_NUMBER() into linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788400/how-do-i-translate-a-query-that-uses-row-number-into-linq) but that is not related to my query.

My query in SQL had Rownum upon the date field and query was

```
select date, Users, (T1.Users - isnull(T2.Users,0)) as UsersAdded
from tableuser T1 
join tableuser T2 on T1.Rownum = (T2.RowNum +1)
```

I am new to LINQ so don't even know how to start on this query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the `RowNum` column in your sample data. You also haven't used `Row_Number ` in your sql query. So this is pretty vague.

Comment: Does that SQL even run?  It looks like you are using a column called `RowNum` instead of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: my table does not has that rownum column, i need to add that using linq and get the below output.

Comment: You need to add a column to your table and populate it, or you need to calculate the row number in your query?

Comment: i need to add rownum column to a temp table so that i can use that table to self join like i have done in my sql query and get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use the date column to find the next lowest date by dong a left outer join using `from`/`where`.

```
var ans = from t1 in tableuser from t2 in tableuser.Where(t2 => t2.Date == tableuser.Where(t3 => t3.Date < t1.Date).Max(t3 => t3?.Date)).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { t1.Date, t1.Users, UsersAdded = t1.Users - (t2?.Users ?? t1.Users)};
```

PS I think your example query may have an issue with the first answer row?

Answer (score -4):

Use LINQ to object.
Refer the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

It will be achieved like this

```js
string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", 
                                  "passionfruit", "grape" };

            var query =
                fruits.Select((fruit, index) =>
                                  new { index, str = fruit.Substring(0, index) });

            foreach (var obj in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
            }

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             {index=0, str=}
             {index=1, str=b}
             {index=2, str=ma}
             {index=3, str=ora}
             {index=4, str=pass}
             {index=5, str=grape}
            */
```

Comment: Suggesting to use `Linq-To-Objects` in a question about Linq-To-Sql is pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Get the result LINQ to SQL into Object and Apply LINQ to Object. It's common sense. Even you can directly Apply Lembda expression over table class.

Comment: So you suggest to use `AsEnumerable()` on the whole table? That would be very inefficient if the table is large. It basically loads the database into memory first.